# Foreach e array associativa multidimensional com apenas um item

Tags: php, loop, foreach, array-multidimensional, array-associativo

Tudo bom pessoal,

Estou enfrentando um problema com foreach em PHP, no qual eu recebo um xml e converto o mesmo para array.

Só que em alguns casos o xml possui apenas um item (Veja o exemplo abaixo)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<blocos>
<versao>1.0</versao>
<material>
<bloco>18:00</bloco>
<sequencia>1</sequencia>
<codigo>00031</codigo>
</material>
</blocos>
```

Convertido para array ele fica assim:

```
Array ( [versao] => 1.0 [material] => Array ( [bloco] => 18:00 [sequencia] => 1 [codigo] => 00031 ) )
```

Quando tento percorrer com foreach os itens dentro de [material] o foreach retorna apenas uma string contendo a informação:

> string '18:00' (length=5)

Em outros xml com mais itens dentro de "material" ele percorre corretamente pois neste caso se transforma em uma array com índices numéricos

Vejam:

```
Array ( [versao] => 1.0 [material] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [bloco] => 07:30 [sequencia] => 1 [codigo] => 00552 ) [1] => Array ( [bloco] => 07:45 [sequencia] => 1 [codigo] => 00042 ) [2] => Array ( [bloco] => 09:45 [sequencia] => 1 [codigo] => 00552 ) [3] => Array ( [bloco] => 13:15 [sequencia] => 1 [codigo] => 00552 ) [4] => Array ( [bloco] => 13:30 [sequencia] => 1 [codigo] => 00042 ) [5] => Array ( [bloco] => 16:00 [sequencia] => 1 [codigo] => 00014 ) [6] => Array ( [bloco] => 16:30 [sequencia] => 1 [codigo] => 00552 ) [7] => Array ( [bloco] => 18:00 [sequencia] => 1 [codigo] => 00031 ) [8] => Array ( [bloco] => 20:45 [sequencia] => 1 [codigo] => 00552 ) [9] => Array ( [bloco] => 21:15 [sequencia] => 1 [codigo] => 00042 ) ) )


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<blocos>
<versao>1.0</versao>
<material>
<bloco>07:00</bloco>
<sequencia>1</sequencia>
<codigo>00042</codigo>
</material>
<material>
<bloco>13:45</bloco>
<sequencia>1</sequencia>
<codigo>00042</codigo>
</material>
<material>
<bloco>16:00</bloco>
<sequencia>1</sequencia>
<codigo>00014</codigo>
</material>
<material>
<bloco>18:00</bloco>
<sequencia>1</sequencia>
<codigo>00031</codigo>
</material>
</blocos>
```

Como contornar isso ?

Answer (score 0):

A resolução do seu problema é simples, mas como você não postou o código, só posso "dar uma dica" imaginando o que seu código faz. Enfim, eu imagino que seu código seja similar a isso:

```
foreach($xml['material'] as $material)
{
    /** código para tratar o material **/
}
```

dessa forma, seu código funciona no segundo exemplo. Para resolver o problema do primeiro exemplo e continuar executando de maneira uniforme, você pode deixar o primeiro "array igual" ao segundo. Ou seja, os dois serem uniformes.

```
$materialArray = isset($xml['material']['bloco']) ? [$xml['material']] : $xml['material'];

foreach($materialArray as $material)
{
    /** código para tratar o material **/
}
```

Basicamente o que o código acima faz é adicionar em um array quando houver apenas um material. Dessa forma, o seu array será similar a:

```
Array ( [versao] => 1.0 [material] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [bloco] => 18:00 [sequencia] => 1 [codigo] => 00031 )) )
```